# Trying to figure out how to store previous searches on my dom

Tags: jquery

I am building a weather app, and I would like to store previous searches.  This is for my bootcamp, so this will not be a prod app, I am thinking I need to use local.storage, but I am not 100% sure.

Question: How do I display previous searches on the previous searches section?
If there a specific jquery command I should be researching?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitWeather').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    if (city != '') {
      $.ajax({

        url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=34fd31758b449ea433e05058c225793c&q=' + city + "&units=imperial&count=10",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
          var widget = show(data);
          console.log("here");
          $("#show").html(widget);

          var widget2 = '';

          for (var i in data.list) {
            if (i > 0 && data.list[i].dt_txt.indexOf("12:00") > -1) {
              console.log(data.list[i].dt_txt);

              var code = [

                '<div class="col-2 day">',
                '<p>',
                data.list[i].dt_txt.split(' ')[0],
                '</p>',
                '<p> Temp: ',
                data.list[i].main.temp,
                ' degrees</p>',
                '<p> Humidity: ',
                data.list[i].main.humidity,
                '%</p>',
                '<p> Wind speed: ',
                data.list[i].wind.speed,
                ' MPH</p>',
                '</div>'
              ];

              widget2 += code.join('');
            }
          }
          $("#5dayforcast").append(widget2);
          $("#city").val('');
        }

      });
    } else {
      $("#error").html('Field cannot be empty');
    }
  });
});

function show(data) {

  console.log("show: ", data);



  return data.city.name + ' (' + data.list[0].dt_txt.split(' ')[0] + ') </h3>' +
    '<p><strong>Temp: </strong>' + data.list[0].main.temp + ' degrees</p>' +
    '<p><strong>Humidity: </strong>' + data.list[0].main.humidity + ' %</p>' +
    '<p><strong>Wind Speed: </strong>' + data.list[0].wind.speed + ' MPH</p>';
  //second function looking for forcast data for day 1 of 5



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation Bard -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Weather App</a>



    <div class=" navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
      <!-- this is the form for the weather search-->
      <form class="weatherSearch form-inline my-2 my-sm-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="city" type="search" placeholder="Search City" aria-label="Search">
        <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="recentCity" class='col-2'>
        <h4>Recent Searches:</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="cityList"></div>
      <div class='col-10'>

        <!-- Thi is the div id = show to display the weather data. -->
        <div class="bg-light text-primary" id="show">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class=row>
      </div>
      <div class='col-2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-8'>

    </div>
    <div class='row'>

    </div>
    <div id="5dayforcast" class='row'>
      <div class="col-2">
        City1
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <h4>5 Day Forcast</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="col-2"></div>


    </div>
  </div>
  </div>







  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A specific jQuery command? No. It's just saving a text field to (whatever), could be local storage, could be a cookie (meh), etc. I'm not sure I understand what the issue is.

Comment: Basically, you want to build an Array of search terms, I think you have `cities`, and store that so when the User returns, you cna suggest those to the User? Remember that a lot of browsers do this already. As was mentioned, you can update a Cookie or use localStorage. Please clarify what you want to have happen specifically and show any attempted code.